# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes randomly, suspecting Nvidia driver

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, freeze

Ubuntu 20.04 freezes randomly, sometimes after 20 minutes, sometimes after several hours.

This means I can't move the mouse nor do anything with my keyboard. If sound is playing it repeats in ~2 second loop. No keyboard combination does anything. Only a hard reboot with the PC power switch gets my computer to restart.

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294971/ubuntu-20-04-random-freezes) I have collected some information, though I am a newbie to these things and can't make any real sense of any of this:

```
free -h

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       4,1Gi       7,3Gi       103Mi       4,0Gi        10Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness

vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
ls -al /var/crash
```

```
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Dez 17 12:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Feb  9  2021 ..
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory
```

```
*-firmware                
   description: BIOS
   vendor: AMI
   physical id: 0
   version: F.42
   date: 05/28/2020
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 42
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 16GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
      product: M378A1G43TB1-CTD
      vendor: Samsung
      physical id: 0
      serial: 719AF9F3
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
      product: M378A1G43TB1-CTD
      vendor: Samsung
      physical id: 1
      serial: 719AF9F7
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 4c
   slot: L1 Cache
   size: 384KiB
   capacity: 384KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 4d
   slot: L2 Cache
   size: 1536KiB
   capacity: 1536KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: 4e
   slot: L3 Cache
   size: 12MiB
   capacity: 12MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=3
*-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: RAM memory
   product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   capabilities: pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a3516000-a3517fff memory:a3520000-a3520fff
    total 8
    drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Dez 17 12:03 .
    drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Feb  9  2021 ..
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory

*-firmware                
   description: BIOS
   vendor: AMI
   physical id: 0
   version: F.42
   date: 05/28/2020
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 42
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 16GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
      product: M378A1G43TB1-CTD
      vendor: Samsung
      physical id: 0
      serial: 719AF9F3
      slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2666 MHz (0,4 ns)
      product: M378A1G43TB1-CTD
      vendor: Samsung
      physical id: 1
      serial: 719AF9F7
      slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: 4c
   slot: L1 Cache
   size: 384KiB
   capacity: 384KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: 4d
   slot: L2 Cache
   size: 1536KiB
   capacity: 1536KiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: 4e
   slot: L3 Cache
   size: 12MiB
   capacity: 12MiB
   capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=3
*-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: RAM memory
   product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   capabilities: pm cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a3516000-a3517fff memory:a3520000-a3520fff
```

```
grep -i swap /etc/fstab
```

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

F.42
```

I'm sorry if any of this is unrelated. I am suspecting my GPU is not working properly, because my programs run much more slowly than on my dual boot Windows on the same system.  Also, I get some libcudart and libcublas errors when running some of my programs, and these seem to be related to my GPU as far as I know.

Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

As requested I ran the commands `dmesg`,`cat /var/log/syslog` ,`journalctl` and this are the results:

[github-files](https://github.com/eli4444/askUbuntu_dmesg/blob/0b7579721cab1f189e70a2a7fc24767d2c771e13/dmesg)

[cat ...](https://github.com/eli4444/askUbuntu_dmesg/blob/0b7579721cab1f189e70a2a7fc24767d2c771e13/cat_thingy)

[journalctl](https://github.com/eli4444/askUbuntu_dmesg/blob/0b7579721cab1f189e70a2a7fc24767d2c771e13/journalctl-lastDayOrSo)

I couldn't paste all this code in here due to body limitation, so I put it on GitHub.

Comment: You need to run a simple command called `dmesg` and post it all.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø I did, as you suggested. I can't make any sense of the outcome though.

Comment: at least try `cat /var/log/syslog` and `journalctl`, this last one is long but necessary.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø have done so. I added 2 new files to the github repo - for ```journalctl``` I added the last 8000 lines, because thats what got displayed in my terminal.. Am I looking for anything specific here? Do I need a certain time interval or does this help already? Thanks already!

Comment: To avoid confusion create separeted files for `cat /car/log/syslog` and `journalctl`. Where are those files?

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø I separated into different files, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Did you installed fake Spotify? Installed new theme or something special related to Desktop Enviroment, yours is GNOME right? How your internet adapter is operating, and when was the last time your computer crashed unexpectedly?

Comment: my Spotify should be legit.. it works fine and I installed it on purpose. I have GNOME, yes. Except I didn't install anything. I am using dual boot with win10 btw. The last time my computer crashed was I think 4 days ago, when I left it alone to run a long program. My internet is working totally fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be giving the possible solutions:

1. Reinstall Gnome:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-common
```

> I'll be updating...

Comment: okay, I have done so. Thank you so much for putting that work into my problem! I will get back to you if I have news, or if it seems to have worked

Comment: Alright, don't forget to mark as right answer if it worked.

Comment: so far, I haven't had any freezes (: hoping it will stay that way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Based in your log errors this solve big part of the issue, if you still have problems open a new question.